# how to react to NSFetchedResultsController updates while needing calculated values from database?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, core-data

I'm displaying some expenses in the tableview, using `NSFetchedResultsController`, and while displaying each cell, I need the average price of all expenses in the database to show some sort of percentage.

I use `NSFetchRequest` to calculate that average value (using the same `NSManagedObjectContext`), and all works fine, except when I want to update the (cached) average value upon the database update. performing the NSFetchRequest on the context, gives outdated results, at any stage of `NSFetchedResultsController`: (controllerWillChangeContent, didChangeObject, didChangeSection, controllerDidChangeContent). Am I doing something wrong?

Calculating the average on `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification` on the context, gives the right value, but I was looking for a solution for not installing extra observers and use the existing NSFetchedResultsController

Comment: How do you calculate the average?  Are you using an NSExpression to get the figure from the database, or using KVC @avg?

Comment: Yes, so that will use the data that's in the store - I guess the FRC delegate methods are all called before the store is updated.  One option would be to use the KVC method, though that might trigger a lot of fetches.  Alternatively, could you do the average calculation yourself: track both count and total, and in the FRC delegate add/subtract for inserts/deletes (or both for updates)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was wondering why I never had that issue - the answer is perhaps because I habitually use KVC. I would recommend this solution as it is the most elegant and concise. Also, you should not worry too much about too many fetches - Core Data tends to optimize this kind of thing quite well under the hood.